# Python: break up dataframe (one row per entry in column, instead of multiple entries in column)

Tags: performance, pandas, python-3.4

I have a solution to a problem, that to my despair is somewhat slow, and I am seeking advice on how to speed up my solution (by adding vectorization or other clever methods). I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
toy = pd.DataFrame([[1,'cv','c,d,e'],[2,'search','a,b,c,d,e'],[3,'cv','d']],
                   columns=['id','ch','kw'])
```

Output is:

[image]

The task is to break up `kw` column into one (replicated) row per comma-separated entry in each string. Thus, what I wish to achieve is:

[image]

My initial solution is the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in toy.itertuples():
    id = x.id; ch = x.ch; keys = x.kw.split(",")
    data = data.append([[id, ch, x] for x in keys], ignore_index=True)
data.columns = ['id','ch','kw']
```

Problem is: it is slow for larger dataframes. My hope is that someone has encountered a similar problem before, and knows how to optimize my solution. I'm using python 3.4.x and pandas 0.19+ if that is of importance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s, then get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for `length`.

Last create new `DataFrame` by `constructor` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
cols = toy.columns
splitted = toy['kw'].str.split(',')
l = splitted.str.len()

toy = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.repeat(toy['id'], l),
                    'ch':np.repeat(toy['ch'], l),
                    'kw':np.concatenate(splitted)})
toy = toy.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (toy)
   id      ch kw
0   1      cv  c
0   1      cv  d
0   1      cv  e
1   2  search  a
1   2  search  b
1   2  search  c
1   2  search  d
1   2  search  e
2   3      cv  d
```

Comment: Thank you, and super-fast as well. I will try it out immediately (I will accept your answer as soon as I have performed a sanity-check). Again, thanks!